How to activate Enterprise Search (Elastic) with Docker Compose?
Although I pulled all the necessary Docker images, I keep hitting this screen when trying to create an Elastic Search Index in the Enterprise Search tab:

They tell me:

In your config/kibana.yml file, set enterpriseSearch.host to the URL of your Enterprise Search instance. For example:
enterpriseSearch.host: 'http://localhost:3002'

Where can I put these since I only have a docker-compose.yml and an .env files?
This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3.8"

volumes:
  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
  metricbeatdata01:
    driver: local
  filebeatdata01:
    driver: local
  logstashdata01:
    driver: local
  enterprisesearchdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  default:
    name: elastic
    external: false

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "  - name: kibana\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - kibana\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/module: elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${ES_MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  enterprisesearch:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/enterprise-search/enterprise-search:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/certs
      - enterprisesearchdata:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config
    ports:
      - ${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}:3002
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=enterprisesearch
      - secret_management.encryption_keys=[${ENCRYPTION_KEY}]
      - allow_es_settings_modification=true
      - elasticsearch.host=https://es01:9200
      - elasticsearch.username=elastic
      - elasticsearch.password=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - elasticsearch.ssl.enabled=true
      - elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority=/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - kibana.external_url=http://kibana:5601
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
            "CMD-SHELL",
            "curl -s -I http://localhost:3002 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/module: kibana
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    mem_limit: ${KB_MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  metricbeat01:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:${STACK_VERSION}
    user: root
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/metricbeat/certs
      - metricbeatdata01:/usr/share/metricbeat/data
      - "./metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:ro"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/sys/fs/cgroup:/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup:ro"
      - "/proc:/hostfs/proc:ro"
      - "/:/hostfs:ro"
    environment:
      - ELASTIC_USER=elastic
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTIC_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - KIBANA_HOSTS=http://kibana:5601
      - LOGSTASH_HOSTS=http://logstash01:9600
    command:
      - --strict.perms=false

  filebeat01:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:${STACK_VERSION}
    user: root
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/filebeat/certs
      - filebeatdata01:/usr/share/filebeat/data
      - "./filebeat_ingest_data/:/usr/share/filebeat/ingest_data/"
      - "./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
      - "/var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    environment:
      - ELASTIC_USER=elastic
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTIC_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - KIBANA_HOSTS=http://kibana:5601
      - LOGSTASH_HOSTS=http://logstash01:9600
    command:
      - --strict.perms=false

  logstash01:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${STACK_VERSION}
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/module: logstash
    user: root
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/logstash/certs
      - logstashdata01:/usr/share/logstash/data
      - "./logstash_ingest_data/:/usr/share/logstash/ingest_data/"
      - "./logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:ro"
    environment:
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - ELASTIC_USER=elastic
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
ELASTIC_HOSTS=https://es01:9200


This previous docker-compose.yml is the merge of two different sources:

ELK suite here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-the-elastic-stack-and-docker-compose
Enterprise Search block from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/docker.html#docker-compose-example

I'm stuck, please help!

Extract your config/kibana.yml from the container, edit it the way you want, mount it with volume.

Thank you, how do you extract config/kibana.yml from the container?


Extract your config/kibana.yml from the container. Typically it's located in /home/kibana/config/kibana.yml, but it depends on KBN_PATH_CONF env variable. Check it just to be sure.

You'll need a running container, then execute
docker cp <containerId>:/home/kibana/config/kibana.yml /path/to/wherever/kibana.yml


Edit the copied file as you need.
Kill the running container and then adjust your docker-compose.yml like so:

kibana:
    ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - /path/to/wherever/kibana.yml:/home/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    ...

That should do the trick.
